# Concurrency in EF4 - How to conditionally create an entity

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

I need to be able to create a new User entity **only if** the provided email is unique.

I've always handled this before by performing a simple `if (!UserSet.Any(...))` before my `AddToUserSet(...)`. However, this is not a concurrent solution and will break under heavy load.

I've been looking into Transactions, but AFAIK I would need to set an UPDLOCK on the SELECT too, but EF4 does not support this.

How does everyone else handle this?

Comment: The only reasonable solution is to introduce a unique index or constraint on the email field and the failure in the app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force locking by including SELECT in transaction:

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    // Create context
    // Check non existing email
    // Insert user
    // Save changes
}
```

This will use serializable transaction which is what you need if you want concurrent solution for inserts - UPDLOCK is not enough to ensure that new record is not added during your transaction.

This can be pretty bad bottleneck so I agree with @paolo: simply place the unique constraint to the database and catch exception during insert if email is not unique.

Serializable transaction from [Books online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx):

> Specifies the following:
>
> ```
>     Statements cannot read data that has been modified but not yet  
>     committed by other transactions.
>
>     No other transactions can modify data that has been read by the  
>     current transaction until the current transaction completes.
>
>     Other transactions cannot insert new rows with key values that
>     would fall in the range of keys read by any statements in the current
>     transaction until the current transaction completes.
> ```
>
> Range locks are placed in the range of key values that match the
>   search conditions of each statement
>   executed in a transaction. This blocks
>   other transactions from updating or
>   inserting any rows that would qualify
>   for any of the statements executed by
>   the current transaction. This means
>   that if any of the statements in a
>   transaction are executed a second
>   time, they will read the same set of
>   rows. The range locks are held until
>   the transaction completes. This is the
>   most restrictive of the isolation
>   levels because it locks entire ranges
>   of keys and holds the locks until the
>   transaction completes. Because
>   concurrency is lower, use this option
>   only when necessary. This option has
>   the same effect as setting HOLDLOCK on
>   all tables in all SELECT statements in
>   a transaction.

Comment: I'm fairly certain this won't work. 2 concurrent users could perform a 'Check non existing email' and both read 'Email Available'. They would then attempt to add the record simultaneously. This is because the SELECT is not using UPDLOCK.

Comment: SELECT is part of the transaction so it uses locking corresponding to the isolation level of the transaction.

Comment: Okay, I have tried this and it appears to work. However, I'm assuming EF will throw an exception upon collision. How should I handle this? Keep rerunning the query? I get Msg 1205 when testing the queries in Management Studio.

Comment: What type of collision do you mean?

Comment: Management Studio throws a 'Msg 1205' on _one_ of the transactions if two transactions are executed simultaneously. I assume EF will throw a similar error too?

Answer (score 1):

in addition to your check, you could add a [unique constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191166.aspx) on the email field directly on the DB